# Why msvc can't find "spdlog/spdlog.h" header?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, spdlog

Code Repository: https://github.com/fastype/fastype

This project use `build.bat` initialize on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2017. It will clone the github repositories and build third party dependencies, then create visual studio sln project file via cmake.

All the cmake config seems right, while not working for spdlog headers.

The error messages are:

```
cannot open "spdlog/spdlog.h" headers.
```

Comment: According to the documentation you are supposed to use `build.bat` to build it, which obtains the dependencies (spdlog, fmt, boost and ICU)

Comment: @M.M  yeah, I write this project, but build.bat and CMakeWindows.cmake seems working not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Check evaluated value of MSVS's project property `"Additional include directories"` (Project properties - C/C++ - General - "Additional include directories"). It lists directories added to compiler's include path.
If there is no needed directory than add it.